# React Native dependencies issues

Tags: react-native, npm, dependencies

I've been working on a ios/android app with react native for the first time and am struggling with dependencies issues. Can someone help me understand what this error message means and how to fix it?
[not enough rep to post the image itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH0n2.png)

Comment: First of all you shouldn't post image of code in question. You should copy paste the error and wrap it in ``` `some code` ```.
Are you using expo?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.